# An issue occur when compiled source code with java 1.6 and run on 1.3 with String.Format() Exception

Tags: java, string, unix

Compiled **String.format("%,.2f", new Object[]{new Double(tranInfo.getAmount())});**

-> **tranInfo.getAmount()** return **double**

and got an exception alert when run on java 1.3 on Sco OpenServer OS :

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
    at FileChangeNotification.displayMessage(FileChangeNotification.java:84)
    at FileChangeNotification.processMessage(FileChangeNotification.java:71)
    at FileChangeNotification.access$2(FileChangeNotification.java:52)
    at FileChangeNotification$1.onChange(FileChangeNotification.java:40)
    at FileChangeNotificationEventHandler.run(FileChangeNotificationEventHandler.java:16)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please kindly show me another code with **String.Format()** to replace above code to work with Java 1.3 on Sco Openserver!!!

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to try to *run* on Java 1.3 (which is [*really ancient*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history) - can you not upgrade?) you should really *build* everything on Java 1.3 as well, just to avoid these problems cropping up at execution time. Otherwise you could well find that some untested code path which looks absolutely fine blows up in production in a completely avoidable way.

For this particular problem, you should look at using a [`NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) instead (e.g. [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)) - but again, I'd strongly advise you to do this as part of recompiling on Java 1.3, *or* upgrading to a more recent version of Java.

Comment: Dear sir , can you give me some example code about **NumberFormat** or **DecimalFormat**

Comment: @Oudam San - [formatting tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/numberFormat.html)

Answer (score 2):

`String.format` simply doesn't exist in Java 1.3. Hence the error. You'll have to implement that method yourself or find a third party library that can work on Java 1.3.

Besides. Java 1.3 is so legacy, it's like using Windows 3.1 in the age of Windows 8! I would strongly advise you to upgrade it to the latest and greatest version.

Comment: It's my obligation to make it works on Sco Openserver Release 5 , The server support on Java 1.3 .